# Asp.Net Core WebApi Internal Server Error after azure virtual directory webdeploy

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried to deploy a **asp.net core mvc** app and a **asp.net core WebApi** to azure.

Both should be run on same url.

I have created a virtual directory under settings:
"**site\wwwroot\webapi**"

And downloaded the publish settings.

I published the **mvc app to:**

Sitename: **example**

Destination URL: **http://example.azurewebsites.net**

The WebApi I published to:

Sitename: **example/webapi**

Destination URL: **http://example.azurewebsites.net/webapi**

But if i try to acces the URL http://example.azurewebsites.net/webapi

i get an Error 500:

**The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.**

I have spend several hours to find a solution, but i could not fix it.

Comment: Cab you post the error message? Should be available on the cloud server.

Comment: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid


**Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'aspNetCore'**

Comment: Is it possibly a web config inheritance issue? Can you edit your question and include the error along with the web.config for both apps? Here an SO answer that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069806/cannot-add-duplicate-collection-entry-of-type-add-with-unique-key-attribute-n

Comment: Thank you that solved the Problem, but every time i republish the project the webconfig is overwritten and i only have a appsettings.json file in my Solution.

Comment: Can you just add an empty handlers section in appsettings.json? Something like this: "Handlers": {}

Another option is to have it respond to requests on a different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the Problem. I created a `Web.RemoveHandlers.config` file next to the `Web.config` file i created in my project, and set its content to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then i edited my .csproj file and added:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Xdt.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="RemoveHandlersFromWebConfig" AfterTargets="_TransformWebConfig">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_SourceWebConfig>$(PublishDir)Web.config</_SourceWebConfig>
    <_XdtTransform>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Web.RemoveHandlers.config</_XdtTransform>
    <_TargetWebConfig>$(PublishDir)Web.config</_TargetWebConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="dotnet transform-xdt --xml &quot;$(_SourceWebConfig)&quot; --transform &quot;$(_XdtTransform)&quot; --output &quot;$(_TargetWebConfig)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

After i run `dotnet restore` in the Package Manager Console.

After Publishing to Azure all worked as expected.

I found this solution on:

https://github.com/nil4/xdt-samples#remove-handlers

Comment: Thanks, only thing I found that works for ASP.NET Core projects in a virtual directory

Comment: Solved my problem too, thank you! Where did you find the log entry "Cannot add duplicate collection entry..."? I couldn't find it anywhere in azure app service logs.